# Error: Max retries exceeded with url in Python

Tags: python, api

I am trying to fetch some data from an API. However, I getting below error.

```
Max retries exceeded with url: /api/search?accept=application%2Fjson&Authorization=Bearer......
```

I am trying following lines of code in python.

```
token = 'aagagagagagagagaggagagag'

def get_val (ont, term):
    
    #set the url
    url = 'https://host:port/api/search'
    
    #set the header
    Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token
    
    header = {
             'accept': */*,
             'Authorization': Authorization,
             }
    
    #set the parameters
    params = {'ontology': ont, 'q': term, 'header':header}
    
    #send request
    response = requests.get(url, header)
    
get_val('mesh', 'ibu')
```

Following is the curl command (through wrapper):

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'https://host:port/api/search?from=0&ontology=mesh&q=ibu&size=10' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer ''
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, there should be another error in your log describing the problem. The MaxRetriesError only means "Because of error X, it retried 3 times. But failed." - Is there anything else?

Comment: Are you saying that curl command works but python request does not?

Comment: Yes, the curl command works

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing your `params` to `requests.get()`so the API probably has a problem returning the correct data and your request fails.

Try to use:

```
requests.get(url, params=params, headers=header)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding 'verify=False' in get function could provide the API response.